# how can I load css with font-face from public folder in Bundle on the Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, bundler, font-face

I have a bundle calling MyBundle.
In bundle on the public folder have css/fontes.css and have too the fontes folder.

In fontes folder have: sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.eot, sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.woff, sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.ttf, sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.svg, sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.eot, sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.woff, sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.ttf, sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.svg, sourcesanspro-light-webfont.eot, sourcesanspro-light-webfont.woff, sourcesanspro-light-webfont.ttf, sourcesanspro-light-webfont.svg.

Above the content fontes.css

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'source_sans_proregular';
        src: url('fontes/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.eot');
        src: url('fontes/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('fontes/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('fontes/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('fontes/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.svg#source_sans_proregular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;

    }


    @font-face {
        font-family: 'source_sans_probold';
        src: url('fontes/sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.eot');
        src: url('fontes/sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('fontes/sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('fontes/sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('fontes/sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.svg#source_sans_probold') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;

    }


    @font-face {
        font-family: 'source_sans_prolight';
        src: url('fontes/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.eot');
        src: url('fontes/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('fontes/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('fontes/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('fontes/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.svg#source_sans_prolight') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;

    }
```

Could anyone help me loading the fonte.css and sources without using the command "asset:dump".

Comment: What? Can you please clarify what you're asking? Do you mean `assets:install` ?

Comment: thanks for your assistence, but I wanted to read straight from the folder public without using the command asset:install.
This would avoid duplication of files.

Answer (score 0):

You could symlink the folder with fonts to the `web` folder.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I'd like read from public folder on MyBundle.

Comment: You can read from it, but you can't make it accessible from the Internet without putting files to `web/` in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You have your css in `public/` folder of your bundle, which enables you to use [assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html) with the cssrewrite filter, to rewrite paths to the real path under web. See [Fixing CSS Paths with the cssrewrite Filter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#fixing-css-paths-with-the-cssrewrite-filter)

All other assets you can install with the symlink option under the `web/` folder to make them accessible:

```
php app/console assets:install web --symlink --relative
```